# How to require a login on a wordpress page with a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, shortcode

When I attempt the following I get Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by......

I'm trying to require a user to be logged in before they access my page with the shortcode on it.

What am I missing? Thanks a million for any help you can offer.

```
add_shortcode( 'guest-posts', 'guestposts_shortcode' );

function guestposts_shortcode( $atts ) {
    auth_redirect();
}
```

Comment: This has to do with the internal structure of how WP renders blog posts. In short, when it reaches the shortcode, it has already begun outputting the page. Does it *have* to be a shortcode instead of just a post setting?

Comment: No, I want to build it the best way i can, this is my first plugin. its more important to me that i learn to best way to put something together. My plugin will allow the user to post after login, then visit paypal once the post is complete. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: Also when the user creates the post they will fill in specific fields which I will manipuplate before creating the actual post. So my shortcode drops a form on the page currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may work if you parse the post content before to render it. Then you should check if you find the shortcode inside the content.

Here is a small generic function to check it :

```
function has_shortcode($shortcode = '') {
    global $post;

    if (!$shortcode || $post == null) {  
        return false;  
    }

    if ( stripos($post->post_content, '[' . $shortcode) !== false ) {   
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now we have to create a function that will check for our specific shortcode :

```
function unlogged_guest_posts_redirect() {
    if(has_shortcode('guest-posts') && !is_user_logged_in()) {
        auth_redirect();
    }
}
```

Then we have to hook our function (I think this can work in "wp" hook, but you can try anohter if it does not) :

```
add_action('wp', 'unlogged_guest_posts_redirect');
```

To finish, we have to ensure that the shortcode won't echo anything :

```
add_shortcode( 'guest-posts', 'guestposts_shortcode' );

function guestposts_shortcode( $atts ) {
    return false;
}
```

Actually we are dealing with shortcodes but we're not using the **WordPress shortcode API**. This functionnality should be done using a **custom field**, it would be simpler !

Comment: The goal is just to build something my user can install, this is why I was thinking plugin. If i'm way off on my approach feel free to send me in a completely different direction.

Comment: You can try this method, it should work (give us you feedback). Alternatively, you can use post_meta (custom fields) with some kind of metabox in the post edit screen, or if this is used on a unique post (or page), this may be set in a plugin's setting page by choosing the post (in a selectbox for instance).

Comment: I still got the headers already sent issue. I was afraid of that because of this "To finish, we have to ensure that the shortcode won't echo anything". That's the function where I am echoing the form out to the page. From what I Understand that augh_redirect funcntion handles the entire process of forcing the login before gaining access to the page. The documentation doesn't explain where it can be used it simply says place <?php auth_redirect()?> at the top of the page and the page will be login protected.

Comment: Good Lord don't be sorry. I'm sorry. Teach me how to fish. Where can I find a wordpress life cycle so I can research where I should hook to make this work? Same error using wp_loaded

Comment: @ShawnBellman I tested the code above and actually the "wp" hook is OK. I just corrected a typo (funtion)... Just make sure you're not logged when you test it. If you want to know more about the WordPress life cycle, you should read the [WordPress Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Are you OK with this ?

Comment: Strategio, I am a Ninny, you are a Ninja. It hit me in my sleep this morning. I never took the call to auth_redirect() out of my guestposts_shortcode function. Grrrrr I'm beyond sorry. Thanks a trillion for all of your assistance, you rock. And thanks for the link to The Wordpress Action Reference; that will come in handy as I move forward I'm sure. To anyone that finds this, the solutino above definitely works! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could instead create a special category, and hook into `template_redirect`:

```
add_filter('template_redirect', function() {
    if (is_single() && in_category('special') && !is_user_logged_in())
        wp_redirect(site_url('/wp-login.php'));
});
```